# returning an object when the return is Promise<void> - legit?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I have an async function that has some database code like this:

```
export async myCode():Promise<void>{

    let fetchData:Array<string> = []
    const result = await SomeDatabaseOperation();
    if(result === 1){
       fetchData.push('success');
    }else{
       fetchData.push('failure');
    }
}
```

and this function is called in `obj.ts` as:

```
async function main(){
   await myCode()
}

main()
```

but, what I now want to do is, also return the array `fetchData`:

```
let myCodeArray = await myCode()
```

But, then function `myCode` returns a promise, so, can I do this :

```
export async myCode():Promise<void>{

    let fetchData:Array<string> = []
    const result = await SomeDatabaseOperation();
    if(result === 1){
       fetchData.push('success');
    }else{
       fetchData.push('failure');
    }
    return fetchData;  // ##### <---------------- notice this change
}
```

I mean, the return type is a Promise but, I'm returning an array. So far, it's not giving me any error, and the code is returning the array, **But, I wonder if this is legit way of doing it?** Are there any things I should notice while doing this? (Like perhaps maybe typescript wraps the array automatically in a promise or something?)

Comment: async functions always return a promise and any non-promise value returned from an async function is implicitly wrapped in a promise; this has nothing to do with typescript, its just how async functions work.

Comment: @BumbleBee here https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/ you can find a good article about promises

Comment: @BumbleBee could you pelase share reproducable example ?

Comment: thanks everyone and @captain-yossarian , I'm sorry, it has database code, so I can't make it reproducible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, the return type is a Promise but, I'm returning an array.

No, you're returning a promise. The *fulfillment* value of that promise will be an array, instead of `void` (which really means the promise fulfillment value will be `undefined`). An `async` function **always** returns a promise. The code you're using is waiting for that promise to settle via `await`, which is why you see an array, not a promise — the promise has been consumed via `await`.

> So far, it's not giving me any error, and the code is returning the array, But, I wonder if this is legit way of doing it?

You're telling users of the function that it will return `Promise<void>`, but in fact it's returning `Promise<string[]>`. In general, no, it's not a good idea to claim something will return X when in fact it returns Y. <s>(I'm surprised TypeScript isn't complaining about it.)</s> And in fact, if we add the missing `function` keyword to that code, [TypeScript *does* complain about the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwMroLYCmAIsMsAEagEDyADgQE6kYQAUAlAFwwAKD+qEAQA8EBHnKMAfDADeAKBhKYDAsgQMsAWVIALAHRwANunQNWO5AaYQAJvg4wAVDABM7ANzyAvvPkEAD1ozZBhQSFhEFBYYPDAAYXRbAg5uPgEhYQA3dFRbGQVlGCM1eDUoXRIyTgBBBiYwYRBkBlQIAHMZAF4YAG0AXUVlKExmlQIQBCNQnuAAd2BUUNxCKooqOkZmTA4vItQ4GFZVSemYLouYAEZ2OSGisuQKtf1aBBBdVgAiSagoCZAX089xg3hgBCMQjuDyUcHKlVIwFe70+XzgiyMGgIQL2yl8RVU6k0j2eiK8YPkQA).

Comment: so the promise resolves returning whatever I put in the return statement? How does the stuff in my return statement get put in a promise?

Comment: @BumbleBee - That's exactly it: the promise the `async` function creates is *resolved to* what you `return` (exactly the way the promise from `then` is resolved to what you return from the `then` callback when using promises explicitly). If you return a simple value, that means the promise is fulfilled with that value. If you return another promise, the `async` function's promise will be fulfilled or rejected depending on what happens to the promise you returned. `throw` in an `async` function rejects the promise.

Comment: (For more on terminology like "resolve to" and "fulfill" vs "resolve" and such, [see my blog](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/). I also go into this stuff in a fair bit of detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)